# Why do we select Entropy Gain as criteria in Decision Tree learning instead of decrease in error rates as a criteria?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I've been following the [ML course by Tom Mitchel](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ninamf/courses/601sp15/lectures.shtml) and in Decision Tree (DT) Learning, the **Entropy Gain** is chosen as ruling criterion for the choice of a feature/parameter `x_i` as child of another feature in DT top-down growth.

Always our goal of selecting a DT is to avoid **overfitting** by minimizing the error rates; **then why don't we use error rate as a ruling criteria for feature/parameter selection in top-down growth of the tree.**

Feature vector for Input data: `X = < x_1, x_2......x_n >`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use error rate as you don't know what it will be in the end. That is, imagine that the tree is eventually of depth 10, and you are on level 2 of the tree, deciding which feature and which threshold to choose. You can't know at this stage what would be the error rate at level 10. So your criteria should only be based on the current level. With that being said, you don't have to use information gain. There are other criterias as well. For example, one such cretiria is Gini impurity, and this is the default cretiria that is used in [scikit learn DecisionTreeClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier).

Comment: But, Information Gain is also based on two consecutive levels and we choose the branch that has higher IG. Even in this case we have no knowledge of the end result; we are just expanding the branch that decreases Entropy the most. Why can't we do the same using Error rate (for the Labeled Training Data).

Comment: Exactly, both information gain and gini impurity are based only on the current node. How would you calculate the error rate based on the current node? Only the leaf nodes have labels (that is, only they provide classification rule), so how would you calculate error rate for a non-leaf node?

Comment: I agree & accept with your view on why Error rate cannot be used as a ruling criteria for expansion. But still there must be strong reasons for choosing Entropy/Gini_impurity as a criterion. I'm still not convinced.

Comment: @vinaykumar2491 you can read more about it here: https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/decisiontree-error-vs-entropy.html. In addition, this may be a more relevant stack exchange site to ask: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/